# Moving IIS6 Metabase from one hard drive to another

Tags: iis-6, disaster-recovery, data-recovery, metabase

I lost the primary hard drive on my web server, and am now faced with a readable hard drive with the old Windows 2003 installation and a virgin installation of IIS6. I need to figure out how to get the IIS6 metabase from the old OS installation to the new OS installation.

I've found lots of information on exporting the metabase from one IIS6 install and importing it into another, but nothing on recovering metabase installation from an inoperable OS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the metabase is just the two XML files, right? ([source](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6929e089-c495-4ac8-8db0-b069b349b7ba.mspx?mfr=true)) If the new server is configured the same/similar to the old I'd just copy over metabase.xml and mbschema.xml and see what happens -- I'd probably try that with the web service stopped(!).

Oh, backup those two files on the new server first, just in case...

Comment: Unfortunately, that just keeps IIS from restarting at all, with the error code 0x80090006. That's not working at all :-(

Comment: Oh sadness. It seemed too logical to work but I had to offer it as a suggestion!